# Inverse Function Algorithm Excel

Tags: algorithm, math, printing, excel-formula, colormath

I am trying to create a dot gain compensation curve in excel. In excel I have 3 columns of data Column 1 = patch ID (1%-100%) Column 2 = Desired Value, and Colum 3 = Measured Value.

I am looking for some math similar to page 2 figure 2 in the below link
[Click Here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1028.9205&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

I was thinking about using minverse but not really sure how to make it work. Any help you could provide would be appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

> If you’re asked to graph the inverse of a function, you can do so by remembering one fact: a function and its inverse are reflected over the line `y = x`. This line passes through the origin and has a slope of 1.

Source: http://www.dummies.com/education/math/calculus/how-to-graph-the-inverse-of-a-function/